# Is there any other method to get the DFT of a signal without actually computing it using normal calculation

Tags: fft, dft, ifft

Is there any other method to get the DFT of a signal without actually computing it using a normal calculation.
Please help me out in this query

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a paradoxon: you can't calculate a DFT by not calculating one. Nothing about that is not "normal calculation".

Comment: Does this mean "can you compute the DFT of a signal without direct computation of the DFT sum"?

Comment: Define "Normal". This question as is sounds like "Is there any way to add two numbers without actually adding them?" or "Is there any way to eat dinner without actually eating?"

Answer (score 1):

There are a few possible answers depending on the signal and your meaning of "normal calculation".

If the signal is stationary, then you might be able to use an old fashioned analog spectrum analyzer, the kind that works by sweeping a narrow-band analog filter across the input signal, and graphing the amplitude results on an X-Y pen plotter.  Then you could estimate the plot heights at various graph points, corresponding to DFT bin frequencies.

If the signal isn't physical, but a vector of sample points, then you might be able to feed those samples to a synthesizing signal generator, and then feed the resulting analog signal to the above type of spectrum analyzer and pen plotter.

If the signal is periodic, and can be described by a closed form equation, then you might be able to symbolically compute or look up the harmonics (in a table, for instance), then sum a Sinc interpolation of those harmonic results to get your desired DFT bin frequency results.

If by "normal calculation", you mean the full O(N^2) 2D complex matrix multiplication, as indicated by the mathematical definition of a DFT, and the length of your desired DFT isn't a prime number, then various factorizations of that matrix will allow you to compute almost the same result (except perhaps with a tiny bit less rounding errors) in O(NlogN) time. See [this method](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwjT6_qvtIvoAhUOPq0KHdKEAxYQFjAAegQICBAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FFast_Fourier_transform).

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to disagree with the fellows here.  Big time.

Yes you can in special cases.

If your signal is a pure real tone (sinusoid) with a whole number of cycles in the DFT frame, all the DFT values will be zero except for a conjugate pair which are directly determinable by your tone parameters.

If your signal is a pure real tone (sinusoid) with a non-integer number of cycles in the DFT frame, you can directly calculate the bin values in O(n) time using the formulas in my article:

- [DFT Bin Value Formulas for Pure Real Tones](https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/771.php)

If your signal is a known sum of component signals fitting the above cases, the DFT of the sum is simply the sum of the DFTs.

Comment: Hmmm.  I wonder how your result for a pure sinusoid compares to the one I put on my old DSP web page few years back. http://www.nicholson.com/rhn/dsp.html#4

Comment: @hotpaw2 Not the same at all.  Calculating just one bin is an O(1) operation.